# Angular 4 *ngFor, ngx-pipes get name of top-level key

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I'm using the ngx-pipes in my ionic 3 app because I am pulling an object of objects from firebase.

I retrieve my objects and turn it into a variable that I can use on the page:

```
getEvents() {
    this.firebaseDatabase.getEvents.subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Events ", data);
        this.events = data;
    }, error => {
        console.log("Events ", error);
    });
}
```

I log the data and it comes back like this:

```
eventIDHashed_1:
    endDateTime:"tomorrow"
    location:"somewhere"
    roles:
        GyyapYhHQDOriruHLvGPKaTOiRp2:"admin"
    startDateTime:"today"
    title:"Arisss & Nathan"
    type:"wedding"
eventIDHashed_2:
    endDateTime:"tomorrow"
    location:"somewhere"
    roles:
        GyyapYhHQDOriruHLvGPKaTOiRp2:"admin"
    startDateTime:"today"
    title:"Jack & Marlana"
    type:"wedding"
```

The way I'm displaying it on the page is a temporary solution, but everything is working fine except the first line.  I need to get the event name (the key) where it says `eventIDHashed_1` and `eventIDHashed_2`

```
<div class="event-container">
    <div *ngFor="let event of events | values; let i = index">
        <span>{{events[i]}}</span>
        <span>{{event.title}}</span>
        <span>{{event.location}}</span>
        <span>{{event.type}}</span>
        <span *ngFor="let role of event.roles | pairs">
            <span>{{role[0]}}, {{role[1]}}</span>
        </span>
        <span>{{event.startDateTime}}</span>
        <span>{{event.endDateTime}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have everything working and am able to retrieve all information, except the actual event ID `<span>{{events[i] | keys}}</span>` This gives me a list of all of the keys inside of it (`endDateTime, location, title, startDateTime...`), but I need to get the id of the event `eventIDHashed_1` and `eventIDHashed_2`

Answer (score 1):

After playing with ngx-pipes, I found that I could use the `pairs` operator fairly simply.  I've changed the template from the above to this:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events | pairs">
    <span>{{event[0]}}</span>
    <span>{{event[1].title}}</span>
    <span>{{event[1].location}}</span>
    <span>{{event[1].type}}</span>
    <span *ngFor="let role of event[1].roles | pairs">
        <span>{{role[0]}}, {{role[1]}}</span>
    </span>
    <span>{{event[1].startDateTime}}</span>
    <span>{{event[1].endDateTime}}</span>
</div>
```

ngx-pairs gives me the key (position [0]) and the value (position [1]) of the `event`